# Printing HTTP status code with requestsed url

Tags: curl

I am using a tool called waybackurls which is returning a list of URLs.

```
waybackurls api.target.com | grep "url"
```

Output

```
https://api.target.com/ws/api/upg/customer-bff/v2/rest/url?=value
```

Now I am trying to validate the return URL through curl. Because it returns lot of false-positive results.  I am able get the http status code only

```
waybackurls api.target.com | grep "url" | xargs -n 1 curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}"
```

Output

```
200
```

what I want output is using curl

```
200  > https://api.target.com/ws/api/upg/customer-bff/v2/rest/url?=value
404  > https://api.target.com/ws/api/redirect_to?=value
```

Is it possible to get this formate with curl request?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check curl manual. You already put http_code, the same for url:

```
waybackurls api.target.com | grep "url" | xargs -n 1 curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code} > %{url_effective}\n"
```